# Saxon HE and XQuery: Unexpected token "<eof>"

Tags: xquery, eof, saxon

I copy paste this example from http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_functions.asp (though I added the namespace declaration):

```
declare namespace local="local";
declare function local:minPrice($p as xs:decimal?,$d as xs:decimal?) as
xs:decimal? {
    let $disc := ($p * $d) div 100
    return ($p - $disc)
};
```

But when I try to run it, the SAXON output is:

```
Error on line 6 column 1 of newq.xq:
XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...v 100 return ($p - $disc) };#:
Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
Static error(s) in query
```

Anyone idea? Bug in SAXON, or is it using another syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not a Saxon bug. The reason for the error is the only thing in your XQuery is a function declaration; there is no expression. You're only allowed to do this if you declare it as a module.

Otherwise you'll actually have to do something in the XQuery...

```
declare namespace local="local";

declare function local:minPrice($p as xs:decimal?, $d as xs:decimal?) as xs:decimal? {
    let $disc := ($p * $d) div 100
    return ($p - $disc)
};

(:Do something...:)
local:minPrice(10,10)
```

Results of running this XQuery (using Saxon 9):

```
9
```

Comment: I have taken the opportunity to improve the error message for this case.